# How to check point on validation metrics in Pytorch lightning?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, tensorboard, pytorch-lightning

When using the following code fragment to log metrics:

```
    def training_epoch_end(self, outs):
        self.__common_epoch_end_report(mode="train")

    def validation_epoch_end(self, outs):
        self.__common_epoch_end_report(mode="validation")
```

and

```
   def __common_epoch_end_report(self, mode: str):
        """
        Args:
            mode: one of ["train", "validation", "test"]
        """
        tb = self.logger.experiment

        acc, conf, f1, mcc = self.__select_metrics_by_mode(mode)

        acc_val = acc.compute()
        f1_val = f1.compute()
        tb.add_scalars('accuracy', {mode: acc_val}, global_step=self.current_epoch)
        tb.add_scalars('F1', {mode: f1_val}, global_step=self.current_epoch)

        self.log(fr'accuracy\{mode}', acc_val, on_step=False, on_epoch=True, prog_bar=True)
        self.log(fr'F1\{mode}', f1_val, on_step=False, on_epoch=True, prog_bar=True)


    def __select_metrics_by_mode(self, mode):
        if mode == "train":
            acc = self.train_acc
            f1 = self.train_f1
            mcc = self._train_mcc
            conf = self.train_confusion
        elif mode == "validation":
            acc = self.val_acc
            f1 = self.val_f1
            mcc = self._val_mcc
            conf = self.val_confusion
        elif mode == "test":
            acc = self.test_acc
            f1 = self.test_f1
            mcc = self._test_mcc
            conf = self.test_confusion
        else:
            raise ValueError("unsupported mode")
        return acc, conf, f1, mcc
```

I verified that `__common_epoch_end_report` is indeed entered both with `mode='train'` and with `mode='validation'`.

However, only the metrics logged from `train` are available for checkpointing:

```
checkpoint_callback = ModelCheckpoint(
        ...
        save_top_k=10,
        monitor=fr'F1\validation'
)
trainer = Trainer(
      ...
        callbacks=[checkpoint_callback],
)
```

Getting the following error:

```
pytorch_lightning.utilities.exceptions.MisconfigurationException: ModelCheckpoint(monitor='F1\validation') not found in the returned metrics: ['loss\\train_step', 'loss\\train_epoch', 'loss\\train', 'accuracy\\train', 'F1\\train'].
```

How to allow check pointing by validation metrics in Pytorch-lightning?

Comment: What is your checkpointing frequency? Maybe PL tries to save a checkpoint before any validation?

Comment: I no longer have access to the code (15 month old question).  For completeness, how to check the checkpointing frequency and why is it related?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! There are a few ways to control the checkpointing behaviour, see https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common/checkpointing_intermediate.html.

It might be that checkpointing interval is set to less than one epoch and validation metric (calculated at the end of epoch) is not available or up to date when saving a checkpoint.